# What docs do I need from my relative in UK to show that I am staying at his home?

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas

I am planning to visit my cousin in UK this Christmas and I am applying for a visit visa.
I need your help regarding this question:

1. Is anyone paying towards the cost of your visit?

My cousin has invited me to stay at his home for my entire visit but I am covering the costs of the travel my self. But how should I answer the question above, considering that my cousin is only helping me with accommodation but he is not paying for my travel costs?
And which documents do I need from my cousin other than his UK passport?
Do I need his bank statement or a document to prove that he owns his own house?